# What is the initial direction from Sydney to Santiago on a great circle?

Tags: flight-path

When flying the great circle route from Sydney to Santiago, what direction do you head leaving Sydney? Does the path leave Sydney heading SE and approach Santiago strictly from the SW, like is shows in the graphic from [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/996/31323)?

[image]

Comment: Very related: [Why isn't the course fixed along an airway?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29784/14897)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the map is accurate. You can see the same thing on [this map from gcmap.com](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=SYD-SCL):

[image]

On a polar orthographic projection, the great circle looks like this:

[image]